# Proper storage of Kiwi

Tags: storage-lifetime, kiwifruit

I bought some kiwi fruit on Friday ( 2 days ago) and left them in the plastic bags from the store... the fruit and veggie plastic at the grocery store . I also had them tied so no air was actually able to get to them. I was going to put them in a bowl when I got home bc that's how I usually store them but I forgot. It says to store them in plastic with ventilation or in a paper bag or fridge. Will the kiwi I have still taste decent or ? I didn't know the reasoning or if keeping it in a bag like I did with no oxygen is bad .  They look alright but I wasn't sure if their was other reasons they would be bad . Any help or suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that a sealed plastic bag wasn't ideal. But if they still look and feel okay, no obvious spoilage, no dark and squishy spots, then you've gotten away with it and they're probably fine.

As with most fruit, storing without ventilation can definitely encourage kiwis to overripen and spoil faster, and they're a relatively sensitive fruit especially once ripe. So I wouldn't have been surprised if yours had fared badly, but on the other hand if they started out underripe and the room wasn't that hot, I'm not surprised if they're still okay.

Sounds like you already know what to do, though: the fruit bowl is good, at least until they're ripe, and once they're ripe the fridge can hold them longer before going bad.

Answer (score 0):

http://m.wikihow.com/Select-and-Store-Kiwifruit?amp=1

That is a helpful link for kiwi

Also make sure you do not put them in same fruit drawer as apples. The gases put off by apples will accelerate the rotting of anything by them.

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't know if they'd still be good to eat since I had them in a tight plastic bag ..

Comment: I am actually at a bit of a loss as to why this answer would be worth of a downvote.   A request to summarize the link in case it is not accessible would be a fair request. but a downvote without a reason?  Not very helpful to anyone.

Comment: @dlb Link-only answers are regarded as non answers and *deleted* if the link doesn't get summarized. We also delete things that don't actually address the specific question that was asked. This one is borderline on both counts; there's just barely enough here that I wouldn't delete but I'm not surprised someone thought it was worth downvoting. It'd be nice if someone had explained this, yes, but not everyone has time and or wants to have to defend their votes, so we certainly encourage voting in general, comment or no.

Comment: @Jefromi I agree on the no summary, and did not see that content was edited out.  It did seem unhelpful on someone's first post to take a downvote without explaining when the OP liked the answer is what bothered me.  I agree that votes do not need defended, usually, but the fact it is a new poster should usually be taken into account.  Your explanation for likely will help them in future.  Me, if I fail to summarize or add extraneous stuff, blast me without addition, I should know.  ;)

Comment: @dlb Sorry, not sure if I said something confusing, but nothing was edited out here. I mentioned deletion as the action we take as moderators when an answer is completely link-only or doesn't address the question at all. (and yes, I certainly agree that it's best to explain things to new users, but I hesitate to suggest voting differently based on the user - the votes are ultimately for the purpose of ordering answers for future readers)